# Using Pandas rolling function on text columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with column values in string format and a datetime index. I want to create a new column which will have a list of values of a column for last two days. Is it possible to achieve this using pandas?

original datafarme:

```
        date col1 col2
0 2018-07-08    a    b
1 2018-07-09    c    d
2 2018-07-10    e    f
3 2018-07-11    g    h
4 2018-07-12    i    j
5 2018-07-13    k    l
6 2018-07-14    m    n
```

Final dataframe:

```
        date col1 col2  col3
0 2018-07-08    a    b   NaN
1 2018-07-09    c    d   NaN
2 2018-07-10    e    f  b, d
3 2018-07-11    g    h  d, f
4 2018-07-12    i    j  f, h
5 2018-07-13    k    l  h, j
6 2018-07-14    m    n  j, l
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df.iloc[:,2].shift(2)+ ',' +df.iloc[:,2].shift(1)
```

**Edit**

We could extend this to a more generic setting,

Define a customized rolling concat function,

```
rolling_cat = lambda s, n: pd.Series(zip(*[s.shift(x+1) for x in range(n)])).str.join(',')
```

Apply the function

```
rolling_cat(df.iloc[:,2], n=2)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But in case I want to do the same for six days, the expression will be too long. I am looking for something like rolling function which will get all the values at one go.

Comment: This is a simple solution that works, was thinking way too complex

Comment: Update answer to accommodate arbitrary days.

Comment: is it possible for it to have a min_period setting like how the rolling window in Pandas functions? ie if its the first record, it only has its own value (window of itself), second record has its value and the previous value and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Since we can only apply functions to numeric columns with the native `rolling` method, we can write our own function to get the values in a tuple and then `join` them as strings:

```
shift = 2

def get_list(x,m): 
    return list(zip(*(x[i:] for i in range(m))))

vals = [', '.join(x) for x in get_list(df['col2'], shift)]

df.loc[shift:, 'col3'] = vals[: -1]
```

**Output**

```
        date col1 col2  col3
0 2018-07-08    a    b   NaN
1 2018-07-09    c    d   NaN
2 2018-07-10    e    f  b, d
3 2018-07-11    g    h  d, f
4 2018-07-12    i    j  f, h
5 2018-07-13    k    l  h, j
6 2018-07-14    m    n  j, l
```

*note: I named your columns: date, col1, col2*

Answer (score 0):

We can imitate the rolling function as follows (where n is the window parameter):

```
n = 3
pd.concat( [df[['col1']].shift(x) for x in range(0,n)], axis=1 )
```

Now you have a DataFrame like this

```
        col1 col1(lag1) col1(lag2)
         'a'      NaN      NaN
         'b'      'a'      Nan
         'c'      'b'      'a'
```

In this way, you can apply the lambda function of your choice along axis=1. In order to solve your question:

```
pd.concat( [df[['col1']].shift(x) for x in range(0,n)], axis=1 ).apply(
           lambda x: ','.join([ str(x.iloc[w]) for w in range(0,n) ]), axis=1)
```

This approach is very flexible because it can be used with pd.concat(df.groupby) plus apply(axis=1)